# How to deploy commited code of react app to Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

I am not very good with github. I have very two doubts. I created a react app using cra and and followed steps of deployment I could find in google.

Now I have two branches main and gh-pages.
[image]

[image]

1. So I want to confirm, that main will contain my source code and gh-pages will hold build code.
2. My committed code will go to main and then I need to run npm run deploy. It will update the gh-pages?

Answer (score 1):

Committing build files directly to git repo is not a good practice, but lets see how this could be possible first.

You have two branches in your git repository: main and gh-pages. Two branches are separated so your code committed to main branch would not update the gh-pages branch. To update the gh-pages branch, you need to switch to gh-pages branch to commit your build. But when you switch to gh-pages branch, it would not contain the changes you have committed on main branch because it was branched out from a previous commit, you must rebase first.

So your git workflow would be:

1. commit your code to main branch
2. rebase gh-pages branch onto main
3. switch to gh-pages branch
4. build your app, commit your build to gh-pages branch
5. force push your gh-pages branch
6. switch back to main branch for future commits

Instead of doing above tedious git operations, you should consider using the [Deploy to GitHub Pages](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages) GitHub Actions. The build and deploy work would be done by the CI/CD systems on cloud, so you don't have to build and commit files locally.